# Access Denied You don't have permission to access "site" on this server using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, access-denied

I've been using selenium with chrome and I've been trying to access a website but I keep receiving this error message:

```
Access Denied You don't have permission to access "website" on this server.
```

The website works fine on my regular chrome browser, but when opened through selenium I receive this error message.

I've tried the regular troubleshooting for the error but it didn't help, I've tried installing firefox but that resulted in another error: "Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities"

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\Ferdinand\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.vitacost.com/MyAccount/Login.aspx')
```

I'm completely stuck here, I tried it another computer and still the same result.

Comment: Are you using Selenium to log in to the site with your username and password?

Comment: Yes, at least I'm trying to. I can't get the log in screen to show up.

Comment: So you get "access denied" when you do the `browser.get()` request shown in the question?

Comment: Yes. Works fine in my regular chrome browser.

Answer (score 3):

If your trying has **Headless** option, I think it might be related to user-agent.
Because some web site block the user-agent with Headless.

So, go to https://www.whatsmyua.info/ to find your user-agent which works in your regular chrome browser and try again with this.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
String userAget = "YOUR USER AGENT";
options.addArguments(String.format("user-agent=%s", userAgent));
```

This is a java code but I believe there is an exactly same way in python.

Answer (score 1):

A bit unclear in which circumstances you are facing the error *..."Access Denied You don't have permission to access "website" on this server...*. However using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) to access the website you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.vitacost.com/MyAccount/Login.aspx')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.h1")))
  print(driver.page_source)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html class="desktop  js flexbox flexboxlegacy no-touch" lang="en" style=""><head class="at-element-marker"><title>
          Login - Vitacost
  </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex,nofollow">
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
  <meta name="description" content="Buy discount vitamins, nutritional supplements, low carb, weight loss supplements and other health products from Vitacost. Vitacost sells top brand vitamins at wholesale cost. Save 33% - 75% on every nutritional product we carry. Why are you paying retail prices?">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Vitacost, vitamin, supplement, buy vitamin, discount vitamin, health supplement, vita, vitamin store, wholesale vitamin, vitacost.com, wholesale vitamin supplement, vitacost vitamin">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.vitacost.com/myaccount/login.aspx">
  <link rel="P3Pv1" href="http:    //www.vitacost.com/w3c/p3p.xml">
  <link href="/res/(19.12.2)/Styles/vitacostCore.min.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="/res/(19.12.2)/Styles/vitacostProduct.min.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="/res/(19.12.2)/Styles/vitacostAux.min.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="/res/(19.12.2)/Styles/vitacostShared.min.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://www.vitacost.com/styles/modules.css?ref050819" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="/res/(19.12.2)/Styles/print.css" rel="styleSheet" media="print" type="text/css">
  <iframe src="javascript:void(0)" title="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; border: 0px; display: none;"></iframe><script src="https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1158.min.js"></script><script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="https://sslwidget.criteo.com/event?a=3439&amp;v=5.5.0&amp;p0=e%3Dexd%26ci%3D%26site_type%3Dd&amp;p1=e%3Dvh&amp;p2=e%3Ddis&amp;adce=1&amp;tld=vitacost.com&amp;dtycbr=29175" data-owner="criteo-tag"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js"></script><script id="socialannex-s13-core" async="" src="//cdn.socialannex.com/s13/v2/s13-main.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://offer.slgnt.us/e146f0b2dfa340dca911e2ac94675415/51bb5e46657842.js"></script><script src="https://static.criteo.net/js/ld/ld.js"></script><script async="" src="//dp.shoprunner.com/2.9.0/sp.js"></script><script id="socialannex-s13" async="" src="//cdn.socialannex.com/partner/2209221/s13.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://tracker.marinsm.com/tracker/async/15b71u0950.js"></script><script src="https://cltgtstor001.blob.core.windows.net/eddb5e6a-4e95-4420-9313-e6876dc0a04b/eddb5e6a4e9544209313e6876dc0a04b_1.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="//bat.bing.com/bat.js" async=""></script><script src="https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/967518976648812?v=2.9.15&amp;r=stable" async=""></script><script async="" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js"></script><script>
  // akam-sw.js install script version 1.3.3
  "serviceWorker"in navigator&&"find"in[]&&function(){var e=new Promise(function(e){"complete"===document.readyState||!1?e():(window.addEventListener("load",function(){e()}),setTimeout(function(){"complete"!==document.readyState&&e()},1e4))}),n=window.akamServiceWorkerInvoked,r="1.3.3";if(n)aka3pmLog("akam-setup already invoked");else{window.akamServiceWorkerInvoked=!0,window.aka3pmLog=function(){window.akamServiceWorkerDebug&&console.log.apply(console,arguments)};function o(e){(window.BOOMR_mq=window.BOOMR_mq||[]).push(["addVar",{"sm.sw.s":e,"sm.sw.v":r}])}var i="/akam-sw.js",a=new Map;navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message",function(e){var n,r,o=e.data;if(o.isAka3pm)if(o.command){var i=(n=o.command,(r=a.get(n))&&r.length>0?r.shift():null);i&&i(e.data.response)}else if(o.commandToClient)switch(o.commandToClient){case"enableDebug":window.akamServiceWorkerDebug||(window.akamServiceWorkerDebug=!0,aka3pmLog("Setup script debug enabled via service worker message"),p());break;case"boomerangMQ":o.payload&&(window.BOOMR_mq=window.BOOMR_mq||[]).push(o.payload)}aka3pmLog("akam-sw message: "+JSON.stringify(e.data))});var t=function(e){return new Promise(function(n){var r,o;r=e.command,o=n,a.has(r)||a.set(r,[]),a.get(r).push(o),navigator.serviceWorker.controller&&(e.isAka3pm=!0,navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(e))})},c=function(e){return t({command:"navTiming",navTiming:e})},s=null,m={},d=function(){var e=i;return s&&(e+="?othersw="+encodeURIComponent(s)),function(e,n){return new Promise(function(r,i){aka3pmLog("Registering service worker with URL: "+e),navigator.serviceWorker.register(e,n).then(function(e){aka3pmLog("ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ",e.scope),r(e),o(1)}).catch(function(e){aka3pmLog("ServiceWorker registration failed: ",e),o(0),i(e)})})}(e,m)},g=ServiceWorkerContainer.prototype.register;if(ServiceWorkerContainer.prototype.register=function(n,r){return n.includes(i)?g.call(this,n,r):(aka3pmLog("Overriding registration of service worker for: "+n),s=new URL(n,window.location.href),m=r,navigator.serviceWorker.controller?new Promise(function(n,r){var o=navigator.serviceWorker.controller.scriptURL;if(o.includes(i)){var a=encodeURIComponent(s);o.includes(a)?(aka3pmLog("Cancelling registration as we already integrate other SW: "+s),navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(e){n(e)})):e.then(function(){aka3pmLog("Unregistering existing 3pm service worker"),navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(e){e.unregister().then(function(){return d()}).then(function(e){n(e)}).catch(function(e){r(e)})})})}else aka3pmLog("Cancelling registration as we already have akam-sw.js installed"),navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(e){n(e)})}):g.call(this,n,r))},navigator.serviceWorker.controller){var u=navigator.serviceWorker.controller.scriptURL;u.includes("/akam-sw.js")||u.includes("/akam-sw-preprod.js")||u.includes("/threepm-sw.js")||(aka3pmLog("Detected existing service worker. Removing and re-adding inside akam-sw.js"),s=new URL(u,window.location.href),e.then(function(){navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(e){m={scope:e.scope},e.unregister(),d()})}))}else e.then(function(){window.akamServiceWorkerPreprod&&(i="/akam-sw-preprod.js"),d()});if(window.performance){var w=window.performance.timing,l=w.responseEnd-w.responseStart;c(l)}e.then(function(){t({command:"pageLoad"})});var k=!1;function p(){window.akamServiceWorkerDebug&&!k&&(k=!0,aka3pmLog("Initializing debug functions at window scope"),window.aka3pmInjectSwPolicy=function(e){return t({command:"updatePolicy",policy:e})},window.aka3pmDisableInjectedPolicy=function(){return t({command:"disableInjectedPolicy"})},window.aka3pmDeleteInjectedPolicy=function(){return t({command:"deleteInjectedPolicy"})},window.aka3pmGetStateAsync=function(){return t({command:"getState"})},window.aka3pmDumpState=function(){aka3pmGetStateAsync().then(function(e){aka3pmLog(JSON.stringify(e,null,"\t"))})},window.aka3pmInjectTiming=function(e){return c(e)},window.aka3pmUpdatePolicyFromNetwork=function(){return t({command:"pullPolicyFromNetwork"})})}p()}}();</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info = {"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"d5fad1d432","applicationID":"38996487,13782876","transactionName":"ZFRVZEJSVxUDURJYDV0edmNgHFQfA1EFXhddRRhcX1RQCExTFUEa","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":310,"agent":"","atts":""}</script><script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={licenseKey:"d5fad1d432",applicationID:"38996487"};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(n,e,t){function r(t){if(!e[t]){var i=e[t]={exports:{}};n[t][0].call(i.exports,function(e){var i=n[t][1][e];return r(i||e)},i,i.exports)}return e[t].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++)r(t[i]);return r}({1:[function(n,e,t){function r(){}function i(n,e,t){return function(){return o(n,[u.now()].concat(f(arguments)),e?null:this,t),e?void 0:this}}var o=n("handle"),a=n(4),f=n(5),c=n("ee").get("tracer"),u=n("loader"),s=NREUM;"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=s);var p=["setPageViewName","setCustomAttribute","setErrorHandler","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","addRelease"],d="api-",l=d+"ixn-";a(p,function(n,e){s[e]=i(d+e,!0,"api")}),s.addPageAction=i(d+"addPageAction",!0),s.setCurrentRouteName=i(d+"routeName",!0),e.exports=newrelic,s.interaction=function(){return(new r).get()};var m=r.prototype={createTracer:function(n,e){var t={},r=this,i="function"==typeof e;return o(l+"tracer",[u.now(),n,t],r),function(){if(c.emit((i?"":"no-")+"fn-start",[u.now(),r,i],t),i)try{return e.apply(this,arguments)}catch(n){throw c.emit("fn-err",[arguments,this,n],t),n}finally{c.emit("fn-end",[u.now()],t)}}}};a("actionText,setName,setAttribute,save,ignore,onEnd,getContext,end,get".split(","),function(n,e){m[e]=i(l+e)}),newrelic.noticeError=function(n,e){"string"==typeof n&&(n=new Error(n)),o("err",[n,u.now(),!1,e])}},{}],2:[function(n,e,t){function r(n,e){var t=n.getEntries();t.forEach(function(n){"first-paint"===n.name?a("timing",["fp",Math.floor(n.startTime)]):"first-contentful-paint"===n.name&&a("timing",["fcp",Math.floor(n.startTime)])})}function i(n){if(n instanceof c&&!s){var e,t=Math.round(n.timeStamp);e=t>1e12?Date.now()-t:f.now()-t,s=!0,a("timing",["fi",t,{type:n.type,fid:e}])}}if(!("init"in NREUM&&"page_view_timing"in NREUM.init&&"enabled"in NREUM.init.page_view_timing&&NREUM.init.page_view_timing.enabled===!1)){var o,a=n("handle"),f=n("loader"),c=NREUM.o.EV;if("PerformanceObserver"in window&&"function"==typeof window.PerformanceObserver){o=new PerformanceObserver(r);try{o.observe({entryTypes:["paint"]})}catch(u){}}if("addEventListener"in document){var s=!1,p=["click","keydown","mousedown","pointerdown","touchstart"];p.forEach(function(n){document.addEventListener(n,i,!1)})}}},{}],3:[function(n,e,t){function r(n,e){if(!i)return!1;if(n!==i)return!1;if(!e)return!0;if(!o)return!1;for(var t=o.split("."),r=e.split("."),a=0;a<r.length;a++)if(r[a]!==t[a])return!1;return!0}var i=null,o=null,a=/Version\/(\S+)\s+Safari/;if(navigator.userAgent){var f=navigator.userAgent,c=f.match(a);c&&f.indexOf("Chrome")===-1&&f.indexOf("Chromium")===-1&&(i="Safari",o=c[1])}e.exports={agent:i,version:o,match:r}},{}],4:[function(n,e,t){function r(n,e){var t=[],r="",o=0;for(r in n)i.call(n,r)&&(t[o]=e(r,n[r]),o+=1);return t}var i=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=r},{}],5:[function(n,e,t){function r(n,e,t){e||(e=0),"undefined"==typeof t&&(t=n?n.length:0);for(var r=-1,i=t-e||0,o=Array(i<0?0:i);++r<i;)o[r]=n[e+r];return o}e.exports=r},{}],6:[function(n,e,t){e.exports={exists:"undefined"!=typeof window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&"undefined"!=typeof window.performance.timing.navigationStart}},{}],ee:[function(n,e,t){function r(){}function i(n){function e(n){return n&&n instanceof r?n:n?c(n,f,o):o()}function t(t,r,i,o){if(!d.aborted||o){n&&n(t,r,i);for(var a=e(i),f=v(t),c=f.length,u=0;u<c;u++)f[u].apply(a,r);var p=s[y[t]];return p&&p.push([b,t,r,a]),a}}function l(n,e){h[n]=v(n).concat(e)}function m(n,e){var t=h[n];if(t)for(var r=0;r<t.length;r++)t[r]===e&&t.splice(r,1)}function v(n){return h[n]||[]}function g(n){return p[n]=p[n]||i(t)}function w(n,e){u(n,function(n,t){e=e||"feature",y[t]=e,e in s||(s[e]=[])})}var h={},y={},b={on:l,addEventListener:l,removeEventListener:m,emit:t,get:g,listeners:v,context:e,buffer:w,abort:a,aborted:!1};return b}function o(){return new r}function a(){(s.api||s.feature)&&(d.aborted=!0,s=d.backlog={})}var f="nr@context",c=n("gos"),u=n(4),s={},p={},d=e.exports=i();d.backlog=s},{}],gos:[function(n,e,t){function r(n,e,t){if(i.call(n,e))return n[e];var r=t();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(n,e,{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(o){}return n[e]=r,r}var i=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=r},{}],handle:[function(n,e,t){function r(n,e,t,r){i.buffer([n],r),i.emit(n,e,t)}var i=n("ee").get("handle");e.exports=r,r.ee=i},{}],id:[function(n,e,t){function r(n){var e=typeof n;return!n||"object"!==e&&"function"!==e?-1:n===window?0:a(n,o,function(){return i++})}var i=1,o="nr@id",a=n("gos");e.exports=r},{}],loader:[function(n,e,t){function r(){if(!x++){var n=E.info=NREUM.info,e=l.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(setTimeout(s.abort,3e4),!(n&&n.licenseKey&&n.applicationID&&e))return s.abort();u(y,function(e,t){n[e]||(n[e]=t)}),c("mark",["onload",a()+E.offset],null,"api");var t=l.createElement("script");t.src="https://"+n.agent,e.parentNode.insertBefore(t,e)}}function i(){"complete"===l.readyState&&o()}function o(){c("mark",["domContent",a()+E.offset],null,"api")}function a(){return O.exists&&performance.now?Math.round(performance.now()):(f=Math.max((new Date).getTime(),f))-E.offset}var f=(new Date).getTime(),c=n("handle"),u=n(4),s=n("ee"),p=n(3),d=window,l=d.document,m="addEventListener",v="attachEvent",g=d.XMLHttpRequest,w=g&&g.prototype;NREUM.o={ST:setTimeout,SI:d.setImmediate,CT:clearTimeout,XHR:g,REQ:d.Request,EV:d.Event,PR:d.Promise,MO:d.MutationObserver};var h=""+location,y={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1158.min.js"},b=g&&w&&w[m]&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),E=e.exports={offset:f,now:a,origin:h,features:{},xhrWrappable:b,userAgent:p};n(1),n(2),l[m]?(l[m]("DOMContentLoaded",o,!1),d[m]("load",r,!1)):(l[v]("onreadystatechange",i),d[v]("onload",r)),c("mark",["firstbyte",f],null,"api");var x=0,O=n(6)},{}],"wrap-function":[function(n,e,t){function r(n){return!(n&&n instanceof Function&&n.apply&&!n[a])}var i=n("ee"),o=n(5),a="nr@original",f=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,c=!1;e.exports=function(n,e){function t(n,e,t,i){function nrWrapper(){var r,a,f,c;try{a=this,r=o(arguments),f="function"==typeof t?t(r,a):t||{}}catch(u){d([u,"",[r,a,i],f])}s(e+"start",[r,a,i],f);try{return c=n.apply(a,r)}catch(p){throw s(e+"err",[r,a,p],f),p}finally{s(e+"end",[r,a,c],f)}}return r(n)?n:(e||(e=""),nrWrapper[a]=n,p(n,nrWrapper),nrWrapper)}function u(n,e,i,o){i||(i="");var a,f,c,u="-"===i.charAt(0);for(c=0;c<e.length;c++)f=e[c],a=n[f],r(a)||(n[f]=t(a,u?f+i:i,o,f))}function s(t,r,i){if(!c||e){var o=c;c=!0;try{n.emit(t,r,i,e)}catch(a){d([a,t,r,i])}c=o}}function p(n,e){if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{var t=Object.keys(n);return t.forEach(function(t){Object.defineProperty(e,t,{get:function(){return n[t]},set:function(e){return n[t]=e,e}})}),e}catch(r){d([r])}for(var i in n)f.call(n,i)&&(e[i]=n[i]);return e}function d(e){try{n.emit("internal-error",e)}catch(t){}}return n||(n=i),t.inPlace=u,t.flag=a,t}},{}]},{},["loader"]);</script><script language="JavaScript" src="/res/(19.12.2)/javascripts/vitacost.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="/res/(19.12.2)/javascripts/vitacost.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="/res/(19.12.2)/JavaScripts/gzchange.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"><!--
  var SPCExperience = true;
  var PPDS = '';
  var PPDNS = '';


  var searchV2Enabled = false;

  var ESCM = '';
  var ESCMoc = '';
  var ESCMos = '';
  var vPageType = 'other';
  var vSLTS = '2019-12-26 14:17:10 -08:00';
  var vDSLT = '0';
  var vSUTCTS = '2019-12-26 22:17:10';
  var vSvr = 'LVDCWEB07';
  var vCustomerID = '';
  var vCustomerSegmentID = '';
  var vProgramIDs = [];
  var vLocale = 'US';
  var vIsSRcheckout_enabled = 'True';
  var vIsProductionEnvironment = '1';

  $jq(document).ready(function(){new vcmc('MyCartHover','TopNav');});
  var bumblebeeUserId='MmU4MmQwZGI1ZTFhMTQ2ZmRkY2Q1ZjRlZWQ1ZGExNzQ=';
  var s_account='vitacost-global';

  var s_linkInternalFiltersAppend='';
  // --></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="/res/(19.12.2)/JavaScripts/shoprunner_init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="//assets.adobedtm.com/3c42c63b493c1af35d8caf2270583ef8ca5bdce4/satelliteLib-ef4882563ec768305944db752a2f61c31a748022.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="https://content.shoprunner.com/VITACOST.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="https://content.shoprunner.com/VITACOST.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="https://assets.adobedtm.com/3c42c63b493c1af35d8caf2270583ef8ca5bdce4/mbox-contents-e848cae1f237cd42fb137c1796f98b33eafc3c2a.js"></script><script src="https://assets.adobedtm.com/3c42c63b493c1af35d8caf2270583ef8ca5bdce4/s-code-contents-71524c2997e1e185948c91ac4b0e3d25a9ad8106.js"></script><style id="at-mbox-default-style">.mboxDefault {visibility:hidden;}</style><style>.at-element-marker {visibility:visible;}</style><!-- Original Facebook Script -->
  <script>
      !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
      n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
      n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
      t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
      document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

      fbq('init', '967518976648812');
      fbq('track', "PageView");
  </script>

  <noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
      src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=967518976648812&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
  </noscript><script>
    (function(w,d,t,r,u){var f,n,i;w[u]=w[u]||[],f=function(){var o={ti:"4031096"};o.q=w[u],w[u]=new UET(o),w[u].push("pageLoad")},n=d.createElement(t),n.src=r,n.async=1,n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=function(){var s=this.readyState;s&&s!=="loaded"&&s!=="complete"||(f(),n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=null)},i=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],i.parentNode.insertBefore(n,i)})(window,document,"script","//bat.bing.com/bat.js","uetq");
  </script>

  <script>
      if (window.vSKU == null || "undefined") {
      window.vSKU = window.vSKUs;
    }
    console.log("bing_: " + window.vSKU);
  window.uetq = window.uetq || [];
  window.uetq.push(
    'event', '',
      {
      'ecomm_prodid': window.vSKU,
      'ecomm_pagetype': window.vPageType
    }
  );
  </script>

    <script>(window.BOOMR_mq=window.BOOMR_mq||[]).push(["addVar",{"rua.upush":"true","rua.cpush":"true","rua.upre":"true","rua.cpre":"true","rua.uprl":"false","rua.cprl":"false","rua.cprf":"false","rua.trans":"SJ-eeb5cac3-8acc-430a-ab8a-ea7c0b375f1e","rua.cook":"false","rua.ims":"false","rua.ufprl":"false","rua.cfprl":"true"}]);</script>
    <script>!function(){function o(n,i){if(n&&i)for(var r in i)i.hasOwnProperty(r)&&(void 0===n[r]?n[r]=i[r]:n[r].constructor===Object&&i[r].constructor===Object?o(n[r],i[r]):n[r]=i[r])}try{var n=decodeURIComponent("");if(n.length>0&&window.JSON&&"function"==typeof window.JSON.parse){var i=JSON.parse(n);void 0!==window.BOOMR_config?o(window.BOOMR_config,i):window.BOOMR_config=i}}catch(r){window.console&&"function"==typeof window.console.error&&console.error("mPulse: Could not parse configuration",r)}}();</script>
    <script>!function(e){var a="https://s.go-mpulse.net/boomerang/",t="addEventListener";if("False"=="True")e.BOOMR_config=e.BOOMR_config||{},e.BOOMR_config.PageParams=e.BOOMR_config.PageParams||{},e.BOOMR_config.PageParams.pci=!0,a="https://s2.go-mpulse.net/boomerang/";if(window.BOOMR_API_key="AZH8B-WP34K-EW2CF-6XVMH-NX5FB",function(){function n(a){e.BOOMR_onload=a&&a.timeStamp||(new Date).getTime()}if(!e.BOOMR||!e.BOOMR.version&&!e.BOOMR.snippetExecuted){e.BOOMR=e.BOOMR||{},e.BOOMR.snippetExecuted=!0;var i,o,r,_=document.createElement("iframe");if(e[t])e[t]("load",n,!1);else if(e.attachEvent)e.attachEvent("onload",n);_.src="javascript:void(0)",_.title="",_.role="presentation",(_.frameElement||_).style.cssText="width:0;height:0;border:0;display:none;",r=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],r.parentNode.insertBefore(_,r);try{o=_.contentWindow.document}catch(O){i=document.domain,_.src="javascript:var d=document.open();d.domain='"+i+"';void(0);",o=_.contentWindow.document}o.open()._l=function(){var e=this.createElement("script");if(i)this.domain=i;e.id="boomr-if-as",e.src=a+"AZH8B-WP34K-EW2CF-6XVMH-NX5FB",BOOMR_lstart=(new Date).getTime(),this.body.appendChild(e)},o.write("<bo"+'dy onload="document._l();">'),o.close()}}(),"".length>0)if(e&&"performance"in e&&e.performance&&"function"==typeof e.performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize)e.performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize();!function(){if(BOOMR=e.BOOMR||{},BOOMR.plugins=BOOMR.plugins||{},!BOOMR.plugins.AK){var a="true"=="true"?1:0,t="",n="nlavsoliomt4gxqfgfsq-f-cd9fb8aee-clientnsv4-s.akamaihd.net",i={"ak.v":25,"ak.cp":"322881","ak.ai":parseInt("198589",10),"ak.ol":"0","ak.cr":67,"ak.ipv":4,"ak.proto":"h2","ak.rid":"74e5043f","ak.r":36234,"ak.a2":a,"ak.m":"a","ak.n":"essl","ak.bpcip":"106.193.89.0","ak.cport":26067,"ak.gh":"104.115.39.191","ak.quicv":"","ak.tlsv":"tls1.3","ak.0rtt":"","ak.csrc":"-","ak.acc":"","ak.t":"1577398629"};if(""!==t)i["ak.ruds"]=t;var o={i:!1,av:function(a){var t="http.initiator";if(a&&(!a[t]||"spa_hard"===a[t]))i["ak.feo"]=void 0!==e.aFeoApplied?1:0,BOOMR.addVar(i)},rv:function(){var e=["ak.bpcip","ak.cport","ak.cr","ak.csrc","ak.gh","ak.ipv","ak.m","ak.n","ak.ol","ak.proto","ak.quicv","ak.tlsv","ak.0rtt","ak.r","ak.acc","ak.t"];BOOMR.removeVar(e)}};BOOMR.plugins.AK={akVars:i,akDNSPreFetchDomain:n,init:function(){if(!o.i){var e=BOOMR.subscribe;e("before_beacon",o.av,null,null),e("onbeacon",o.rv,null,null),o.i=!0}return this},is_complete:function(){return!0}}}}()}(window);</script><script>bazadebezolkohpepadr="1326392439"</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.vitacost.com/akam/11/4f0f2637" defer=""></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://mpsnare.iesnare.com/script/logo.js"></script><script src="https://assets.adobedtm.com/3c42c63b493c1af35d8caf2270583ef8ca5bdce4/scripts/satellite-592dd26e64746d5067001727.js"></script><script src="https://assets.adobedtm.com/3c42c63b493c1af35d8caf2270583ef8ca5bdce4/scripts/satellite-59cd065664746d6b7a00613f.js"></script><script src="https://assets.adobedtm.com/3c42c63b493c1af35d8caf2270583ef8ca5bdce4/scripts/satellite-5b4fab4564746d104700041e.js"></script><script src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
  /*mboxHighlight+ (1of2) v1 ==> Response Plugin*/
  window.ttMETA=(typeof(window.ttMETA)!='undefined')?window.ttMETA:[];window.ttMETA.push({'mbox':'globalMbox','campaign':'','experience':'','offer':''});window.ttMBX=function(x){var mbxList=[];for(i=0;i<ttMETA.length;i++){if(ttMETA[i].mbox==x.getName()){mbxList.push(ttMETA[i])}}return mbxList[x.getId()]}
  </script><iframe src="https://content.shoprunner.com/srsec/sra.html?partner=VITACOST" id="sr_tracking_connector" name="sr_tracking_connector" title="content" aria-hidden="true" class=" sr_iframe_hide" style="display: none !important; height: 0 !important; width: 0 !important;"></iframe><iframe src="https://content.shoprunner.com/sso.html?purl=https://www.vitacost.com/MyAccount/Login.aspx" title="shoprunner_secure_sso" aria-hidden="true" class=" sr_iframe_hide" style="display: none !important; height: 0 !important; width: 0 !important;"></iframe><script async="" src="https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-1141144.js?sv=6"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//cltgtstor001.blob.core.windows.net/eddb5e6a-4e95-4420-9313-e6876dc0a04b/eddb5e6a4e9544209313e6876dc0a04b_2_1568798940.js"></script><script async="" src="https://script.hotjar.com/modules.297b225e0b92ebb96f25.js" charset="utf-8"></script><style type="text/css">iframe#_hjRemoteVarsFrame {display: none !important; width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; opacity: 0 !important; pointer-events: none !important;}</style><script src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1022050475/?random=1577397021494&amp;cv=9&amp;fst=1577397021494&amp;num=1&amp;bg=ffffff&amp;guid=ON&amp;resp=GooglemKTybQhCsO&amp;eid=376635470&amp;u_h=768&amp;u_w=1366&amp;u_ah=728&amp;u_aw=1366&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_his=2&amp;u_tz=330&amp;u_java=false&amp;u_nplug=3&amp;u_nmime=4&amp;gtm=2oac61&amp;sendb=1&amp;ig=1&amp;data=event%3Dgtag.config&amp;frm=0&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vitacost.com%2FMyAccount%2FLogin.aspx&amp;tiba=Login%20-%20Vitacost&amp;hn=www.googleadservices.com&amp;async=1&amp;rfmt=3&amp;fmt=4"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.socialannex.com/s13/v2/service/get_config.php?siteid=2209221&amp;callback=s13callback_1577397021692" async=""></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.socialannex.com/s13/v2/service/get_button_small_html.php?siteid=2209221&amp;divid=show_provider_small&amp;callback=s13callback_1577397023318" async=""></script></head>
  <body style="" class="email-modal-overlay-noScroll">
  ```