# How to automate secure encrypted sites in Selenium using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, encryption

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to do automation by opening a login page in Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
```

I tried to test some sites like - 'https://www.google.com/',etc. which is working perfectly fine.

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/'
browser.get(url)
```

I'm trying to open below url,

```
url = 'https://yesonline.yesbank.co.in/index.html?module=login'
browser.get(url)
```

I got the following error in selenium browser while the url is working fine without selenium.

> **Access Denied**
>
> You don't have permission to access
> "http://yesonline.yesbank.co.in/index.html?" on this server.
>
> Reference
> #18.ef87d317.1625646692.41fe4bc0

But when I'm trying to just open the base url, it is opening but the site gets loads partially and keep showing loading.

```
url = 'https://yesonline.yesbank.co.in'
browser.get(url)
```

I feel like I am missing out something while opening the login url which I'm not able to get what exactly.

I also tried changing the webdriver i.e with Firefox.

```
url = 'https://yesonline.yesbank.co.in'
firefox_browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

And guess what, it was opening!
But as soon as I'm trying to get the login page (even by manually using the mouse and clicking login page).

```
url = 'https://yesonline.yesbank.co.in/index.html?module=login'
firefox_browser.get(url)
```

'firefox_browser' is getting closed with an session reset error.

Can someone help me how to open secure sites in selenium. Or is there any other way to get it done.

Comment: Do you try to get api response from this link?

Comment: I would advise you to setup a simple http request monitoring and look at the request you're doing. Compare the selenium call against an ordinary Chrome call. There might be differences which the bank site (like a useragent) checks.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58679718/selenium-how-to-avoid-access-denied-page

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Thanks & I tried that, but no change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's finally working with chrome-driver by adding some arguments to it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options = options)
```