# Access Denied You don't have permission to access site in Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So This is my Python Code ,
After running this code when you reload the webdriver i face the error **Access Denied You don't have permission to access site**

I have also tried he Headless Method but that doesn't also work .

````
from time import sleep
import random
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



class StockData:
    def __init__(self):
#         chrome_options = Options()
#         chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36')
#         self.driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Arth\Desktop\codes\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)
#         agent = self.driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36")
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile,executable_path=r'C:\Users\Arth\Desktop\codes\geckodriver.exe')

        
    def goSite(self):
        driver=self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/volume-gainers-spurts")
        sleep(3)
    def start(self):
        driver=self.driver
        #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@title, 'Refresh') ]").click()
        sleep(1)
        names=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title, '_blank') ]")
        print(names)
        
bot=StockData()
bot.goSite()
bot.start()```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Denied You don't have permission to access "site" on this server using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246179/access-denied-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-site-on-this-server-using-ch)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Access Denied You don't have permission to access site
```

...implies that [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) initiated [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) *Browsing Context* is being [detected as a BOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873022/how-to-make-selenium-script-undetectable-using-geckodriver-and-firefox-through-p/58879076#58879076) and further navigation is blocked.

---

Historically [NSE India](https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/volume-gainers-spurts) have been long known to be protected by [**Bot Manager**](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/products/security/bot-manager.jsp) an advanced bot detection service provided by [**Akamai**](https://www.akamai.com/) and the response gets **blocked**.

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Clicking on Get Data button for Monthly Settlement Statistics on nseindia.com doesn't fetch results using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872920/clicking-on-get-data-button-for-monthly-settlement-statistics-on-nseindia-com-do/59874462#59874462)
- [Dynamic dropdown doesn't populate with auto suggestions on https://www.nseindia.com/ when values are passed using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457093/dynamic-dropdown-doesnt-populate-with-auto-suggestions-on-https-www-nseindia/62457673#62457673)

---

### Solution

To conceal the fact that the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) / [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) is automation driven you can follow the steps mentioned in the discussion [How to Conceal WebDriver in Geckodriver from BotD in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959399/how-to-conceal-webdriver-in-geckodriver-from-botd-in-java/70064475#70064475)

Comment: Thanks a lot brother for the links it helped me with the issue

Comment: chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)                                           This above line when i added in code it's working !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need selenium for what you are doing. Just use the `requests` library.

We first make a request to the main site, to get the cookies for our second request. Then we make our second request to the API.

`request.Session()` lets use store the cookies from the previous request.

You can see the request they make in the network tab, in your browser.

I've used their API Url, below.

```py
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.headers["User-Agent"] ="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0"

session.get("https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/volume-gainers-spurts")

result = session.get("https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-volume-gainers")

print(result.json())
```

I've tested it and it should work.